# going back to previous if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

im creating a adventure game in python .

```
name = input('what is your name : ')
print(f'welcome {name} to this game ! ')
choice = input('do you want to play the game ? ')
if choice.lower() == 'y':
    print('ok , cool ! ')
else :
    print('bye')
advent = input('there is a road . do you want to go left or right ? ')
if advent.lower() == 'left':
     path = input('you have reached an river . do you want to swim or cross a bridge ? ')

 if path.lower() == 'bridge':
     print('you have crossed the bridge congrats ! ')
 if path.lower() == 'swim':
     croc = input('now you are swimming . oops ! there is a crocodile . what do you want to do ? ')
     if croc.lower() == 'go back to the river bank':
           bank_path = input('now you are in the river bank and do you want to cross the bridge ? ')
         if bank_path == 'cross the bridge':
             # how do i go back to the if statement in line 12 
     if croc.lower() == 'go ahead':
         print('you are ded -_- ! . The croc ate you ')
```

now in line 16 , if the user wants to go back to the river bank , there is only one choice which is crossing the river . now how do i make the if statement which is line 12 to work in line 19

Comment: and what's wrong if you put the same `print('you have crossed the bridge congrats ! ')` on line 19 (that's what 12 does) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reuse code in python, [functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) are the way to go:

```
def crossed_bridge():
    print('you have crossed the bridge congrats ! ')
```

However in your case, the code you want to reuse is so short that you can just call `print()` another time.